# Broken: Find box in VS is in left to right

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I hit the wrong keyboard shortcut this morning in Visual Studio and managed to flip text direction for the the find box from right to left to left to right. Of course I have no idea how to flip it back.

Any one know the key combination?

[image]

Thanks, Keith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it would appear the oldest trick in the book fixed my problem:

1. Turn computer off
2. Turn computer on